# Like url from Wordpress incorrect

Tags: wordpress, facebook-likebox

I'm helping out as admin on a WordPress site and we are adding the ability to "Like" individual post and pages and are using the following code;

`<div class="fb-like" data-href=”<?php the_permalink(); ?>” data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

The Like button displays correctly but the url for some reason has an " added in the end rendering the link to become invalid. If I "echo" the result of the_permalink it displays the correct url.

**Example;**
Like is clicked on *http://my.blog/is-cool/* but the displayed url on my timeline is *http://my.blog/is-cool/"*.

Answer (score 1):

Your double quote marks around the `<?php the_permalink(); ?>` are incorrect - they are the 'curly quotes'.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but should I completely remove the quotation marks (") or replace them with something else and if so what?

Comment: Just replace them with normal quotation marks - not sure if I made myself clear, the_permalink is wrapped in typographers quotes which won't work - http://www.typographyforlawyers.com/?page_id=1322/

Comment: I have tried all variations of quotation marks and even tried without, but end up with the same problem.. For some reason an extra " is added to the Like URL. All ideas on why this is are mer than welcome!